# Apache Rewrite URL not working

Tags: apache-2.4, redirection

The existing configuration of the server is as below for redirect

## host: animal.ca

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName animal.ca:80

```
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^animal\.ca\connectee$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.animal.ca/fr_ca/connect.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

########################################################################################
# host:animal.ca

        ServerName animal.ca:80

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^animal\.ca$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.animal.ca [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Redirection of URL is not working as expected and I suspect that there should be change in ServerName for both the Virtual Hosts.

Need some advice on the same to make redirection work